# Is there any point in undersizing VARCHAR columns?

Tags: oracle, performance, varchar

[Googling around](http://www.google.com/search?q=oracle%20varchar2%20performance) there seems to be mixed reports whether the size of a `VARCHAR2` column in Oracle impacts performance or not.

I would like to give the question of `VARCHAR` size a little twist and hope to get some insight in this:

Given (multiline) free-text fields (*not* short stuff like names) that you want to store in an (Oracle) database, is there any point (wrt. performance or otherwise) in *not* maxing out the `VARCHAR` capacity (`VARCHAR2(4000)` on Oracle) but choosing a smaller value such as 1024 or 512 because that will likely be sufficient in 98% of the cases anyway.

Comment: Related [ask Tom question](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1145132537055)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does impact memory usage, especially when a client program has to allocate enough memory to receive a dataset.

Bear in mind that a lot of apps (especially web apps) use UTF-8 which is a multi-byte character set. As such, you should really consider characters rather than bytes.

If I was expecting over a thousand characters, then I'd actively consider a CLOB. I'd be thinking about whether it will store plain text or some form of markup (wiki / html ?), usage with non-Euro languages. The Questions and Answers here, for example, would be CLOB, but comments can fit in a VARCHAR.

If you max out a VARCHAR, then in six months someone will want to make it bigger again, and you'd be kicking yourself for not using a CLOB.

Comment: UTF-8 will generally use one byte for one character for western languages.  It's multi-byte in the sense that it allows for multi-byte "escape" sequences to represent non-Western characters.

Answer (score 8):

Generally there are no performance considerations although there are [side issues](http://hrivera99.blogspot.com/2008/05/why-is-varchar2-oversizing-bad.html) that might matter to you. The limit for a `varchar` should be thought of as a constraint like any other - it is there to enforce a business rule.

IMO the question you should be asking is "Do I want to prevent the free-text data stored in this field being longer then *n* bytes/chars" - that is the only determining factor when choosing between `varchar(512)` and `varchar(4000)`.

Note that I am assuming you are talking about `varchar` the SQL type - the situation is different with `pl/sql` and choosing the length [can be crucial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/datatypes.htm#LNPLS334) for memory allocation reasons.

Comment: Thanks. As far as my (very limited) experience goes, any "business rule" stating a limit between "500 - 3999" is simply arbitrary, that is, someone just liked the number. IMHO, if I'm going for free-text and there are no implementation consequences (the context of this question), either it's maxed out (4000) or it's not free-text. --- The point I'm trying to make in this comment: I think there won't ever be a business rule helping to choose btw. 512 and 4000 (unless it's: "as many chars as possible")

Comment: If it is really "as many chars as possible" then as @gary says, you should consider a `clob`, shouldn't you?

Answer (score 4):

If a smaller value will work for 98% of the cases, but it takes a Varchar2(4000) to work for 100% of the cases, then you have little choice but to **use the larger value**.  Creating a separate table for 2% of the values and then coordinating inserts/selects etc. would add complexity that would obliterate any memory or performance benefits from not extending the field.